# Creating a program that squares an array?

Tags: arrays

So I am trying to create a program that takes a 2D array, and then returns the same array with each element being the square of what it was ... for example

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

should become

```
1 4 9
16 25 36
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matrixReader {
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("src/matrix"));
    File output = new File("src/output");
    int i = input.nextInt();
    int j = input.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[i][j];
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        for (int y = 0; y < i; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < j; x++) {
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    int[][] squareArray = new int[i][j];
    for (int y = 0; y < i; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < j; x++) {
            squareArray[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(array[i][j], 2);
        }
    }

    PrintWriter printOutput = new PrintWriter(output);

    for (int y = 0; y < i; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < j; x++) {
            printOutput.print(squareArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

}

}
```

The problem is that it displays a indexOutOfBoundsException for array[i][j] = input.nextInt() when it is first getting the inputs.  I don't know if my text file is messed up or if it has something to do with the way I wrote my code.  My text file is supposed to display i on one line, j on the next, then all the array numbers on a single line, like this:

```
2
3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Any help?  I can't figure out what's going on

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` are the fixed values you read in from the text file. Since `i` is `2`, the array has indexes `0,1` and calling `array[i]` is `array[2]` which is out of bounds and throws an error.

For filling in different parts of your array, you need to be using the loop variables `y` and `x`.

```
array[y][x] = input.nextInt();
```

Same change needed in your squarearray code.

(Hint: variable names that mean something, like `totalNumberOfRows` might have made this easy to see).

Comment: In your case, what's array[j][i]?  Probably not. When you have `for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)` the `x` is counting over the columns in the array. You need to use that with `array[y][x]` so your code covers all the values in all the columns in the array. Using `array[j][i]` is trying to use the same array location over and over again, because `i` and `j` aren't changing - and they're outside the array.